# Replacing the regular navigation bar with an image! (Titanium Appcelerator)

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I tried adding     barimage:'corkboard.jpg',  but it does not work but it does only works for colors barColor='#fff',

I'm still new and learning and I really would like to implement this :S

var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:'TESTING',
    barimage:'corkboard.jpg',
    backgroundImage:'background.png',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Window properties are case sensitivity!

- barimage FALSE
- barImage CORRECT

barImage works only on iPhone!

Is the image location correct? The code below is in the Resources/app.js and the image is the same folder.

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:'window',
    barImage: 'bg.png',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    url:'win1.js'
});
```

Comment: I found if you use this method in a navigation group the title text is rendered behind the background image